# How to trigger the event manually once the ajax content's script is executed completely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, jquery-events

I am loading a `html` page with `script` section(render the `JQuery` UI) via `AJAX`. This html page contains more number widgets. In success function of Ajax, I am accessing the `UI` controls by its `JQuery` UI class names, but none of the class names are added i.e., script is not executed. If I access the same after 100ms using setTimeOut its working.

Please refer the below code:

```
  var self = this;
  $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: "html",
                cache: true,
                success: function (str,sta,xhr) {
                        $("#samplefile").html(str);

             setTimeout(function() {
                        self.reg($("#samplefile .ui-widgetui"));
                    },100);
           }
        });
```

Its working fine but I want to access this without settime out. Can anyone  please  suggest on this?

Comment: updated the query

Answer (score -1):

It sounds perhaps that you are trying to access the DOM before everything is initialized. Have you tried wrapping the initialization of you ajax request in a jQuery `$(document).ready()` call? This makes sure that your DOM is in a initialized state before getting triggered.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I have called the ajax request in document.ready of source file only but not works

Comment: The `setTimeout` is clearly making it a timing thing, so whatever could be delaying some sort of initialization seems like a good starting point.